# Why do Meereen's people not call rulers "Your Grace"?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Spoilers ahead:

.

.

.

After Dany becomes Queen of Meereen, her new subjects refer to her as "Magnificence" rather than "Grace":

> "Magnificence," prompted Reznak mo Reznak, "will you hear the noble  Hizdahr zo Loraq?"

And after he becomes king, [Hizdahr zo Loraq](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Hizdahr_zo_Loraq) also insists on being called "Magnificence" rather than "Grace". For example, in [chapter 67 of ADWD](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons-Chapter_67):

> "Ser Barristan." Hizdahr yawned again. "What hour is it? Is there news of my sweet queen?"
>
> "None, Your Grace."
>
> Hizdahr sighed. "'Your Magnificence,' please. Though at this hour, 'Your Sleepiness' would be more apt."

Why do the Meereen people not use "Grace" to address to their rulers?

Comment: I don't understand why you would think people from other countries would have the same honourifics for their rulers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The obvious answer is that "Your Grace" is a Westeros tradition, as noted by Reznak in [ADWD Chapter 55](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons-Chapter_55):

> "Not Grace," the seneschal complained. "That style is Westerosi..."

But [hamfast42](http://www.reddit.com/user/hamfast42) also brings up a good point in this [r/asoiaf thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/2e9xm5/spoilers_all_why_the_people_of_mereen_dont_say/) which gets at the real answer.

In the Ghiscari cities of Slaver's Bay, the [Temple of the Graces](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Temple_of_the_Graces) houses priestesses, called [Graces](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Graces):

- Green Grace - the High Priestess.
- Blue Graces - Healers.
- Red Graces - Cult prostitutes.
- White Graces - Young girls of noble birth too young for the pleasure palaces.
- Pink Graces - unknown specialty who attend on the Green Grace.
- Gold Graces.
- Purple Graces.

It would be rude to refer to the monarch using the same title as priestesses, healers, and prostitutes.

Comment: I think “Oh mighty Nurse-Whore” has quite a nice ring to it. Dany can be altogether too fussy about these details in my opinion. \*Paul is immediately incinerated by a dragon\*.

Answer (score 0):

Your grace is Westerosi. We might say in English that China has an emperor, but in Chinese they didn't have an emperor title but rather used the term Huángdi, similarly while, Dany is a Queen, the Meerenese use their equivalent style to address Dany.